# I have two date variables, date_from and date_to, Can I read in every value in between?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

Please excuse my lack of knowledge in this but I am new to PHP. We are doing a project on codeigniter and I am pulling my hair out!

I am doing a project booking site. Where a user can search properties by date and make a booking request if those dates are available. I have a property table, a request table (status will change depending on if the host accepts it) and a bookings table. Once the host accepts a request from a user, the status of the request will be updated on the request table and a new entry will be made into the bookings table

Our lecturer wants us to use this logic.

If a property is booked from the 1st-5th of January then there will be 5 entries into the bookings table for each of those dates.

Can you provide any advise on how I would do a loop for reading in each date between and inclusive of $date1 and $date2?

This is my controller

```
public function acceptBooking()
{
    $request_id = $this->input->post('request_id');
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $property_id = $this->input->post('property_id');
    $date1= $this->input->post('date1');
    $date2 = $this->input->post('date2');
    $status = $this->input->post('status');

    $data = array(
        'request_id'=>$request_id,
        'user_id'=>$user_id,
        'property_id'=>$property_id,
        'date1' => $date1,
        'date2' => $date2,
        'status' => $status
    );

    $this->model_booking_status->update_status($request_id,$data);
    $this->model_booking_status->insert_bookingToDB();

    $this->load->view('view_accept_success');

}
```

and my Model

```
public function insert_bookingToDB(){
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $property_id = $this->input->post('property_id');
    $date1= $this->input->post('date1');
    $date2 = $this->input->post('date2');
    $status = $this->input->post('status');

    for(*****){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO bookings(user_id,property_id,property_date)
    VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($user_id) . ",
            " . $this->db->escape($property_id) . ",
            " . $this->db->escape($property_date) .")";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }

}

function update_status($request_id,$data)
{
    $this->db->where('request_id', $request_id);
    $this->db->update('requests', $data);
}

}
```

I have the function update_status working which allows the host to accept the request and this gets updated on the database for the user to see. I honestly don't know where to start with the loop on reading in dates and entering each date into the database. I have *** my loop just to show ye what I am thinking of doing, The date format on my database is YYYY-MM-DD and is property_date on the bookings table.

Thanks a mill and sorry again if I am coming across like an idiot!

SOLVED :)

```
while (strtotime($date1) <= strtotime($date2)) {
        echo "$date1\n";
        //use +1 month to loop through months between start and end dates
        $date1 = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date1)));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bookings(user_id,property_id,property_date)
    VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($user_id) . ",
            " . $this->db->escape($property_id) . ",
            " . $this->db->escape($date1) .")";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: You need a new lecturer... Why in the world would you want to make this into a bloody nightmare to use by storing separate dates in the database, instead of just storing from and to dates, and do any parsing in the program logic?

Comment: Believe me we have stressed this. She has chosen this to be as awkward as possible.

Comment: But, as for the original question, you could just do a for-loop and use DateTime and ->format("+1 day")

Comment: I figured it out! I used the strtotime function. Thanks for the help anyway! :)

Comment: (`from the 1st-5th of January then there will be 5 entries into the bookings table for each of those dates` for a total of - (fires up a steam-powered pneumo-mechanical calculator) - 26 - no, wait, 25 entries? You need a lecturer update.) `I figured it out!` You are welcome to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
while (strtotime($date1) <= strtotime($date2)) {
    echo "$date1\n";
    //use +1 month to loop through months between start and end dates
    $date1 = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date1)));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bookings(user_id,property_id,property_date)
VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($user_id) . ",
        " . $this->db->escape($property_id) . ",
        " . $this->db->escape($date1) .")";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```